# iOS 8 css rotate element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios8, mobile-safari

I am trying to get css rotate properties to work on iOS 8. The basic idea is, as you scroll down the page, the card will flip around. This works on desktop and on mobile iOS 7, but not iOS 8.

What we are doing is updating the rotateY, among other properties as the user scrolls.
Here is some JS code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        scrollValue = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (scrollValue <= section1Top) {
            scaleValue = 1 - (0.333 * scrollValue / section1Top);
            rotateyValue = 180 * scrollValue / section1Top;
            rotateValue = -10 * scrollValue / section1Top;

            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + scrollValue * 0.33 );

            if (rotateyValue < 90) {
                  $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg)');
                  $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_tyffon.jpg)');
            }else {
                  $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                  $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_1.jpg)');
            }

        }else if (scrollValue < section2Top - 1100){
            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);
            $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_1.jpg)');
            $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(0.667) perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg)');
        }else if(scrollValue <= section2Top){
            scaleValue = 0.667;
            rotateyValue = 180 + 360 * (scrollValue - section2Top + 1100) / 1100;
            rotateValue = -10;

            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);

            if (rotateyValue < 270 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_1.jpg)');
            }else if (rotateyValue < 450 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_tyffon.jpg)');
            }else  {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_2.jpg)');
            }
        }else if (scrollValue < section3Top - 1100){
            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);
            $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_2.jpg)');
            $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(0.667) perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg)');
        }else if( scrollValue <= section3Top ){
            scaleValue = 0.667;
            rotateyValue = 540 + 360 * (scrollValue - section3Top + 1100) / 1100;
            rotateValue = -10;

            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);

            if (rotateyValue < 630 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_2.jpg)');
            }else if (rotateyValue < 810 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_tyffon.jpg)');
            }else  {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_3.jpg)');
            }
        } else if (scrollValue < section4Top - 1100){
            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);
            $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_3.jpg)');
            $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(0.667) perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg)');
        } else if(scrollValue <= section4Top){
            scaleValue = 0.667;
            rotateyValue = 900 + 360 * (scrollValue - section4Top + 1100) / 1100;
            rotateValue = -10;

            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);

            if (rotateyValue < 990 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_3.jpg)');
            }else if (rotateyValue < 1170 ) {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_tyffon.jpg)');
            }else  {
                $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleValue + ') perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotateyValue + 'deg) rotate(' + rotateValue + 'deg) scaleX(-1)');
                $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_4.jpg)');
            }
        } else {
            $('#card').css('left', cardLeft + section1Top * 0.33);
            $('#card').css('background', 'url(img/card_4.jpg)');
            $('#card').css('transform', 'scale(0.667) perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg)');

        }

     });
```

And the css on the card:

```
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
height: 508px;
width: 330px;
margin-top:-254px;
margin-left:-165px;

background: url(../img/card_tyffon.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;

-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(1, 1);
transform: scale(1, 1);

-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #000000;
cursor: pointer;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, not sure what changed in iOS 8, but it is driving me crazy.

**EDIT:**
So I played with it a little more and it looks like on Safari, the card only displays when rotateY is 0 (the card is flat). On chrome however, it will show the rotation when I stop scrolling, it's like the rotation isn't applied until the end.

**EDIT:**
It seems like the setting of 'position' is what is causing it to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the positioning that made it disappear. So all I did was wrap the card in a container div and put the fixed positioning on that. Worked like a charm.

container css:

```
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
height: 508px;
width: 330px;
margin-top:-254px;
margin-left:-165px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue where my rotation was causing my front "card" to go underneath its grandparent div's background in iOS 12 Safari. The fix for me was to create a block formatting context on the card's parent div using the transform3d hack.

My structure:

```
<div class="hasBackground">
    <div class="bfcHack">
        <div class="card">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// Create BFC because mobile safari 12 is broken
.bfcHack {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```